# Parsing excel sheet columns into NSArray in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv, nsarray

I made few csv files by converting excel docs. Below code am using to read the csv file. I tried parse by index but it returning the row values instead of columns

```
  NSString *sourceFileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GanditProState" ofType:@"csv"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
  NSMutableArray *csvArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  csvArray = [[sourceFileString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] mutableCopy];
  dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  NSLog(@"dict %@",dict);
```

can anyone give me solution to parse the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the first row contains column names.

```
// Split the file into lines
NSMutableArray *lines = [source componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"].mutableCopy;
// Get the first line as column headings
NSArray *keys = [lines.firstObject componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
// Initialize the result object, an array of dictionaries with 
// headings as keys and arrays as values for each key
NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i<keys.count; i++) {
   [result addObject:@{keys[i] : [NSMutableArray array]}];
}
// Remove the first line which is already stored in keys array
[lines removeObjectAtIndex:0];

for (NSString *line in lines) {
   // Get a list of all values
   NSArray *columns = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
   for (int i = 0; i<keys.count; i++) {
       // Insert the value into the array of the proper key
       NSMutableArray *values = result[i][keys[i]];
       [values addObject:columns[i]];
   }
}
```

I think this is better than just a dictionary with column headings as keys because it preserves the order of the columns. But if you don't need that you can simplify to just have a dictionary with keys and arrays.

Comment: No it is not. It is returning an array of columns.

Comment: am sorry its returning columns only but program is terminating with 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 44 beyond bounds [0 .. 43]

Comment: Make sure you have all column headings filled out.

Comment: all headings are filled but still its crashing

Comment: Well it still sounds like it is working well. You should open a new SOF question and post details about your crash. I am sure it is because you are accessing values that do not exist, maybe because of empty cells in the CSV. Just add checks for `nil` in above code.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove line:

```
NSMutableArray *csvArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

And change it to line:

```
 NSArray* csvArray = [[sourceFileString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] mutableCopy];
```

Every element of the row [divided](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) by ",". To parse every row you can use this:

```
[csvArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString* lineString, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSArray* lineComponents = [lineString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        //TODO: do smth this lines components;
    }];
```

But I think, more better is using some library to parse of csv, for [example](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser).

*P.S.*
componentsSeparatedByString: - returns NSArray.